# Using RTOS support in OpenOCD

Tags: rtos, openocd, freertos, gdb

I can see that OpenOCD is [RTOS aware](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/) and it supports FreeRTOS, which I'm using at the moment.

I have looked at various sources and cannot seem to figure how to use this feature.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed the documentation for this amazing feature is rather poor, however there is [a guide for ChibiOS](http://www.chibios.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=chibios%3acommunity%3asetup%3aopenocd_chibios#debug_with_threads). Basically this boils down to:

1. pass `-rtos auto` to `{TARGET_NAME}.cpu configure` in the Tcl configuration script
2. use [thread commands in](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) `gdb`, where `info threads` is the probably the one you will use most

Comment: For those struggling (like me); here is how to start openocd for smt32f4 discovery: `openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32f4discovery.cfg -c "stm32f4x.cpu configure -rtos auto"`